# Is is possible to go invisible in iChat?

Tags: ichat

I want to be able to go invisible in iChat, like I can via Gmail. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Gmail in iChat before 10.7 you can't go invisible. I'm using [Adium](http://adium.im/) to be able to go invisible when I login via Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just click on the Green light that says available and you will had all these options as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: iChat doesn't show `Invisible` for me!

Comment: Yup, I don't see it either.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running? I'me running 10.7 Lion

Comment: More important than which version of OS X, what service (AIM? Y!? MSN? Jabber?) are you connecting too? In the case of Jabber, at least knowing who the host is will help.

Comment: Not working for me either on 10.7 Lion. I've got Jabber on Google Talk, Bonjour and Facebook configured.

Comment: Be reminded that the invisible feature only displays if you have MobileMe setup.